# Improving Montgomery product

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I am reading the paper "A Cryptographic Library for the Motorola DSP56000" (http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-46877-3_21.pdf) which describes a trick to speed-up calculation of the Montgomery product.
What I don't get is the improvement step (between the two algorithms at the end). All parameters are separated into words and the improvement step says that instead of $N'$ it is enough to only use $n'_0$ (the first word of $N'$). So the rest of $N'$ is not needed! What??!!

Can someone please give me some hints, why is this the case?

[image: Monty1]

[image: Monty2]

[image: Monty3]

Answer (score 0):

- `Montgomery-Reduce(T,N,b)` produces a result equivalent modulo $N$ to $Tb^{-1}$, then
- `Montgomery-Reduce(Montgomery-Reduce(T,N,b),N,b)` produces a result equivalent modulo $N$ to $Tb^{-2}$
- `Montgomery-Reduce(Montgomery-Reduce(Montgomery-Reduce(T,N,b),N,b),N,b)` produces a result equivalent modulo $N$ to $Tb^{-3}$

and so forth. Since $R = b^n$, reducing $n$ times with third parameter $b$ produces a result equivalent modulo $N$ to $Tb^{-n} \equiv TR^{-1}$.